# NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0'

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I have an array of array called dummyData and i'm having a problem in returning the count  as of my array comments as the number of rows in my table.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSArray *commentsArray=[[dummyData objectAtIndex:section] valueForKeyPath:@"comments"];
NSLog(@"Comments: %d", [commentsArray count]);

if (section == didSection) {
    return [[[dummyData objectAtIndex:section] valueForKeyPath:@"comments"] count];
}
return 0;
}
```

and it gives me this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (2 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

This is my array:

```
dummyData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[dummyData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", @"badge.png",@"Got Strike! at", @"Alex Shin",
                                                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                                [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"James", @"30 minutes ago", @"Great Shot!", @"https://c676132.ssl.cf0.rackcdn.com/_84A2468-50cf361795eb2.jpg", nil]
                                                            forKeys:
                                                                [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Kim", @"10 minutes ago", @"I should have seen it.", @"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tBFQC9y-ZpM/Tmb8DaeYEmI/AAAAAAAAA9M/TahVx2IiQsE/s400/Bowling+and+Best+Bowling+Player+Shalin+Zulkifli+cover.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Matt", @"5 minutes ago", @"Nice", @"http://www.beverlyhillsmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/Ashton-Kutcher-Hollywood-Stars-Rich-and-Famous-Movie-Stars-Star-of-the-Week-Beverly-Hills-Magazine-Hollywood-Magazines--300x336.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]]

                                                           , nil] , nil]

                     forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo", @"credit",@"credit_label", @"name", @"comments", nil]
                                                          ]];

[dummyData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", @"location_icon.png",@"Checked in at", @"Jessah Ouano",
                                                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Matt", @"1 hour ago", @"Welcome!", @"http://www.beverlyhillsmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/Ashton-Kutcher-Hollywood-Stars-Rich-and-Famous-Movie-Stars-Star-of-the-Week-Beverly-Hills-Magazine-Hollywood-Magazines--300x336.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Steve", @"47 minutes ago", @"You'll enjoy here.", @"http://www.oozyleaks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Taylor-Lautner.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]]



                                                           , nil] , nil]

                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo", @"credit",@"credit_label", @"name", @"comments", nil]
                      ]];

[dummyData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", @"location_icon.png",@"Checked in at", @"Richard Son",
                                                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pinky", @"3 hours ago", @"I saw it", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tom", @"1 hour ago", @"realy?", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Caty", @"11 minutes ago", @"yes", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]]



                                                           , nil] , nil]

                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo", @"credit",@"credit_label", @"name", @"comments", nil]
                      ]];

[dummyData addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", @"badge.png",@"Got a Strike! at", @"Dexter Dulay",
                                                          [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Matt", @"12 minutes ago", @"Take the opportunity", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dex", @"11 minutes ago", @"Maybe later", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Drew", @"9 minutes ago", @"Alex should win", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alex", @"9 minutes ago", @"As always. :)", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]],

                                                           [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Luis", @"2 minutes ago", @":D", @"http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/Klipsch-Image-S4-II-Black-Lifestyle.jpg", nil]
                                                                                       forKeys:
                                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"dateline", @"body", @"image_url", nil]]



                                                           , nil] , nil]

                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo", @"credit",@"credit_label", @"name", @"comments", nil]
                      ]];
```

my question is, how can i return the number of comments per section. because comments array hav different number of contents or count.

Comment: NSLog(@"Comments: %d", [commentsArray count]); returns 5,3,2 and 3

Comment: I tried to return 2 in numberOfRowsInSection and it worked. but i didn't get the expected result. it returns 2 rows for all section.
I also tried returning 1 or 3 and both makes the same error as posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSArray *commentsArray=[[dummyData objectAtIndex:section] valueForKeyPath:@"comments"];
NSLog(@"Comments: %d", [commentsArray count]);

if (section == didSection) {
    return [[[dummyData objectAtIndex:section] valueForKeyPath:@"comments"] count];
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: that's exactly the same code you posted in the question